# network activity indicator not appearing in iOS app

Tags: ios, activity-indicator

In my iOS app, I want to show the network activity indicator in the top status bar.

I've added the following:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

But the activity indicator never appears.

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

    // load sets
    [self loadSets];
}

-(void)loadSets{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"in loadSets");

        // show loading animation
        UIView *loadingView = loadingIndicator;
        loadingView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
        [self.view addSubview:loadingView];
        [loadingIndicator startAnimating];

        self.userSets = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // re-initialize userSets

        dispatch_async(bgQueue, ^{
            NSString *userURLString = [userBaseUrl stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.json?auth_token=%@", username, auth_token];
            NSLog(@"userURLString %@", userURLString);
            NSURL *userURL = [NSURL URLWithString:userURLString];
            NSData * userData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:userURL];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if(userData){
                    [self fetchSets:userData];
                    // remove loading animation
                    [loadingView removeFromSuperview];
                }else{
                    // error with authentication - should log out and require relogin
                    //                [self logoutClick];
                }
            });
        });

    });
}

-(void)fetchSets:(NSData *)responseData{
    NSError * error;
    NSDictionary * json = [NSJSONSerialization
                           JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                           options:kNilOptions
                           error:&error];
    if(json){
        NSArray *sets = [json objectForKey:@"sets"];
        for (NSDictionary *currentSet in sets){
            Set *userSet = [[Set alloc] init];
            userSet.name = [currentSet objectForKey:@"name"];
            userSet.videoURL = [[currentSet objectForKey:@"media"] objectForKey:@"mp4"];
            userSet.gifURL = [[currentSet objectForKey:@"media"] objectForKey:@"gif"];
            userSet.imgURL = [[currentSet objectForKeyedSubscript:@"media"] objectForKey:@"img"];
            userSet.setID = [currentSet objectForKey:@"id"];
            [self.userSets addObject: userSet];

        }
        NSLog(@"trying to reload table data with userSets length %d", [self.userSets count]);

        [self.collectionView reloadData];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"done loading table data");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not blocking the main thread are you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322534/networkactivityindicatorvisible-not-showing-till-its-too-late

Comment: Show more relevant code.

Comment: @rmaddy I added my code

Comment: @wcochran I don't think I'm blocking the main code (code shared above)

Comment: where is the method call you are asking about in the added code?

Comment: @wcochran I added it above

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line where you set the network indicator visible. Is that line ever reached when you run your app?